# Problem installing OS 22.04.2 LTS Jammy Jellyfish with TREK-60

Tags: usb-installation

I am trying to install OS Lubutu because I had the Login problem where my password is correct but keeps flashing back into login page, even system recovery didn't help.
So I've decided to use a USB Drive to install Version 22.04.2 into my computer with TREK-60, I used Rufus to convert my USB Drive, which is successful, but after my computer's system booted up, nothing is on the home screen, it's just the wallpaper of a Jellyfish on the left, I can only right-click to see some stuff such as "Create Launcher".

Did I do something wrong when installing? If you need more info, do ask me!

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to describe; in the title you mention 22.04.2 but not if you're talking about Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server? or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop?  You also mention Lubutu?? but did you mean Lubuntu there? and thus you're not using Ubuntu but Lubuntu?  I don't know what you mean by Trek-60, but a search online tells me it's a vehicle "*management and surveillance*" platform used in managing fleets of cars? but I'm not sure how that relates. Sorry I'm lost.

Comment: Does your TREK-60 system have two displays? Is it possible the installer window is on the other display? On most systems if you press Super+P (Windows key +P) you can toggle the displays to mirror or extend. This sometimes brings the installer to the current display.

Comment: "*my password is correct but keeps flashing back into login page*" might be a classic symptom of a *desktop crash*. Desktop crashes may occur due to hardware incompatibility or due to a poorly-chosen software setting. Note the exact time of an event, then login to a console and check your logs for that time. Also check your /var/crash directory for .crash files